# Navigating with safeArgs in Kotlin throws and error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-safe-args

I have a fragment that can be either navigated to via a bottom navBar without arguments or from a different fragment with arguments. The navigation itself works perfectly fine but as soon as I add my arguments it crashes.

I'm unsure how much code is needed, so sorry if it's not complete:

This is my navigation fragment:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="fh.wfp2.flatlife.ui.views.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Flatlife"
    tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/todoFragment"
    android:name="fh.wfp2.flatlife.ui.views.TodoFragment"
    android:label="Todos">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_todoFragment_to_addTodoFragment"
        app:destination="@id/addTodoFragment" />
    <argument
        android:name="taskname"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="isImportant"
        app:argType="boolean" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/addTodoFragment"
    android:name="fh.wfp2.flatlife.ui.views.AddTodoFragment"
    android:label="AddTodoFragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_addTodoFragment_to_todoFragment"
        app:destination="@id/todoFragment" />


</fragment>
</navigation>
```

This is my **addTodoFragment**:

```
class AddTodoFragment : Fragment(R.layout.add_task_fragment) {

private lateinit var binding: AddTaskFragmentBinding

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
 
    binding = AddTaskFragmentBinding.bind(view)
    binding.bAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding.etAddTodo.text.isNotEmpty()) {
           // viewModel.onAddTodoClicked(binding.etAddTodo.text.toString(), 
binding.cbImportant.isChecked)
           findNavController().navigate(
                AddTodoFragmentDirections.actionAddTodoFragmentToTodoFragment(
                    binding.etAddTodo.text.toString(), binding.cbImportant.isChecked
                )
            )
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(it, "The task field can't be empty", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            
        }
    }

}
}
```

This is how I'm trying to get the arguments in **TodoFragment**.

```
private val args: TodoFragmentArgs by navArgs()
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
//setting binding and other onClickListeners but they work fine

//reading args
//this i thought would work because then args only get read if not null
args?.let { //debugger stops here and app crashes
        if(args.taskname.isNotEmpty())
        viewModel.onAddTodoClick(Todo(name = args.taskname, isImportant = args.isImportant))
    }

/*second try which I took directly from developers.android but which doesn't make sense in my case i 
think because the args could be null I guess

val todoName = args.taskname
    val isImportant = args.isImportant
    viewModel.onAddTodoClick(Todo(name = todoName, isImportant = isImportant))
*/

}
```

This is the error message i get:

[image]

I hope it is clear what I mean, otherwise, I'll update the question. It'll probably be something simple but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: _"It's only when navigating to the TodoFragment without passing arguments"_ I don't understand how it's possible. The code wouldn't compile because the action expects 2 arguments.

Comment: @Onik the action referred isn't navigated in the scenario without any arguments. 
When navigating without arguments I go from HomeFragment -> TodoFragment (with bottom navigation)

When navigating with arguments i go from AddTodoFragment -> TodoFragment.

Comment: I believe that's the problem. When `args?.let` is invoked when having the bottom navigation, `args` are being lazy initialised and the exception is thrown.

Comment: @Onik hm ok. But with the variation of PiyushMaheswari in the answer below it should work then, right? Because that gets initialized immeditately i guess? I'll try that again but it didn't work before sadly.

Comment: Try not using `TodoFragmentArgs` at all, but only Fragment's `arguments`.

Comment: @Onik thank you!! This works for me!
I have a couple of other issues regarding logic on my side but your tipp fixed this issue. Thanks a lot!
If you like to formulate an answer I would accept it otherwise I would either just update my question or post the answer and give credit to you. Do you know why this works or better phrased: why TodoFragmentArgs doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

So credit to @Onik for the idea to leave SafeArgs away. I needed to dump the SafeArgs class call for **receiving** the arguments and it looks like this now. This is definitely not the cleanest way I guess but I don't know yet why the SafeArgs call doesn't work and I'm too new to Kotlin to write the following code in a cleaner way. But it works, for now.

```
arguments?.let {
        var myArg1: String? = null
        var myArg2: Boolean
        arguments?.getString("argument1")?.let { arg1->
            myArg1= arg1
        }
        arguments?.getBoolean("argument2")?.let { arg2->
            myArg2= arg2

            if (myArg1!= null)
                //do logis with args
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val args = arguments?.let {
    SecondFragmentArgs.fromBundle(
        it
    )
}
if (args != null) {
    firstDataList = args.taskName
    secondDataList = args.isImportant
}
```

This is how the receiving fragment code should look like. This should work.

Comment: findNavController().navigate(
    FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment(
        taskName,
        isImporatant
    )

Comment: i tried this but this doesn't work though. I still get the same error code. (i will update the post so the error code is visible)

Comment: Yes i did. I use binding but the syntax is the same as i am using. The app crashes when navigating to the fragment without arguments set though, so i'm not even able to get to the fragment which sends arguments if that makes sense.

Comment: Then I guess the binding logic might be the culprit.

Comment: I wouldn't think so because I'm not even navigating to that fragment yet. If i leave out the receiving code for the arguments I can navigate fine. It's only when navigating to the TodoFragment without passing arguments.